# What is "sylthane" in the context of a "sylthane bag"?

Tags: meaning

Frederick Forsyth's novel [*Icon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icon_(novel)) makes reference to a "sylthane bag" in the possession of a British character.

The context suggests that this is a small plastic bag of some form, but sylthane is not a material I am familiar with, so I tried looking it up online. Once I filter out the uses of "Sylthane" as a fantasy character name, I'm left with only the *Icon* text and a message board discussion (unrelated to the book) in questionable taste, which uses the word in passing. The message board context supports the idea that sylthane is a Britishism for a material used to make plastic bags.

Is there a more widely-used synonym for sylthane, or is this a niche material?

Comment: It's possibly just a 'brand name' invented by the author for some colour.

Comment: sounds a bit like celophane- which *is* a plastic bag material.

Comment: I note that the book was set 4 years ahead of when it was published. Was it possibly a "futuristic" material that didn't exist at the time of publishing?

Comment: @KillingTime: The book and the message board discussion (which is entirely unrelated to the book) both use the word as a genetic material word, not a brand name.

Comment: @SteveBennett: The affect of the book (and Forsyth’s work in general) is very grounded in reality, so it’s unlikely to be a sci-fi neologism. Also, given that I can find an apparently unrelated British source using the word casually, I’m inclined to believe it’s more akin to a dialect term.

Comment: It's a [Canadian trademark](http://www.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/viewTrademark.html?id=537121&lang=fra) from the late 1990s for a type of varnish sold by [Peinture Syltech Inc](https://opencorporates.com/companies/ca_qc/1143023605), but that might be a coincidence.

Comment: There's also a 1950s plastic called synthane, so it might be a typo - [see page 65 here](https://www.pearl-hifi.com/06_Lit_Archive/02_PEARL_Arch/Vol_16/Sec_53/Electronics/Electronics_1953/Electronics_11_Nov_1953.pdf)